# How to get user-level access to modifier keypresses in console app?

Tags: keyboard, console

I need to get access to modifier-key state for a console app I'm writing (a personalized editor).

Are there any packages/libs/whatever that provide this access?

I cobbled the following from somewhere, but it only works if you're root, and I don't really want to mess about at root-level.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int kbhit(void)
{
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int ch;
    int oldf;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);

    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~0000172 ; //~(ICANON | ECHO);

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

    ch = getchar();

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);

    return ch;
}

enum MODKEYS
{
    SHIFT_L = 1,
    SHIFT_R = 2,
    CTRL_L = 4,
    CTRL_R = 8,
    ALT_L = 16,
    ALT_R = 32,
};

int chkmodifiers()
{
    int mods=0,keyb,mask;
    char key_map[KEY_MAX/8 + 1];    //  Create a byte array the size of the number of keys

    //event1 - got by inspecting /dev/input/... 
    FILE *kbd = fopen("/dev/input/event1", "r");
    if (kbd == NULL)
    {
        printf("(chkmodifiers) ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //permission - got to be root!
        return 0;
    }

    memset(key_map, 0, sizeof(key_map));
    ioctl(fileno(kbd), EVIOCGKEY(sizeof(key_map)), key_map);    //  Fill the keymap with the current keyboard state

    keyb = key_map[KEY_LEFTSHIFT/8];
    mask = 1 << (KEY_LEFTSHIFT % 8);
    if (keyb & mask) mods += SHIFT_L;

    keyb = key_map[KEY_RIGHTSHIFT/8];
    mask = 1 << (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT % 8);
    if (keyb & mask) mods += SHIFT_R;

    keyb = key_map[KEY_LEFTCTRL/8];
    mask = 1 << (KEY_LEFTCTRL % 8);
    if (keyb & mask) mods += CTRL_L;

    keyb = key_map[KEY_RIGHTCTRL/8];
    mask = 1 << (KEY_RIGHTCTRL % 8);
    if (keyb & mask) mods += CTRL_R;

    keyb = key_map[KEY_LEFTALT/8];
    mask = 1 << (KEY_LEFTALT % 8);
    if (keyb & mask) mods += ALT_L;

    keyb = key_map[KEY_RIGHTALT/8];
    mask = 1 << (KEY_RIGHTALT % 8);
    if (keyb & mask) mods += ALT_R;

    return mods;

}


int main()
{
    puts("Press a key!");

    char ch=0;
    int n=0,m;

    while (ch != 'q')
    {
        n = kbhit();
        if (n != -1)
        {
            m = chkmodifiers();
            ch =  (char)n;
            printf("You pressed '%c' [%d]\n", ch, n);
            if ((m & SHIFT_L) == SHIFT_L) printf(" .. and ls\n");
            if ((m & SHIFT_R) == SHIFT_R) printf(" .. and rs\n");
            if ((m & CTRL_L) == CTRL_L) printf(" .. and lc\n");
            if ((m & CTRL_R) == CTRL_R) printf(" .. and rc\n");
            if ((m & ALT_L) == ALT_L) printf(" .. and la\n");
            if ((m & ALT_R) == ALT_R) printf(" .. and ra\n");

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the actual modifier key events, or do you just need to know their state when pressed together with "proper" keys? Xterm-compatible terminals do provide the latter.

Comment: @ak2: how can I get what you suggest - if it is workable pls put it in an answer that I can accept.

Comment: @ak2: PS - with X it is easy since the X event system provides it, I'm here referring to consoles (CLI) (not terminals in a GUI (X) environment)

Comment: I don't mean X events, but xterm key codes, i.e. the character sequences sent for each key press. In a bash shell, press Ctrl+V followed by the key combination in question to see what each one sends.

Comment: @ak2: xterm is a terminal emulator for the X Window System

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I take it you're only interested in getting this to work in the Linux text console then. Would have been helpful to make that clear in the question. The Linux console doesn't encode modifiers into keycodes, but I presume I'm not telling you anything new there. However, the [showkey](http://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey) command shows events for all keys including the modifier keys, without requiring root rights, so there must be a way to do it. I'd recommend looking at its source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [libtermkey](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/), a terminal key input library that recognises special keys (such as arrow and function keys), including "modified" keys like `Ctrl-Left`.

Another option might be to enhance the functionality of [charm](https://github.com/mcandre/charm), a minimal ncurses copy.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, it has always been really hard to have this kind of information. You can only get a "keycode" and, of course, it means different things depending on what combination of OS, keyboard and terminal you use.

You'll find a complete list of those keycode on your OS with a call to [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap).

```
$ xmodmap -pke
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = ampersand 1 ampersand 1 dead_caron dead_ogonek dead_caron dead_ogonek
keycode  11 = eacute 2 eacute 2 asciitilde Eacute asciitilde Eacute
[...]
keycode 244 = XF86Battery NoSymbol XF86Battery
keycode 245 = XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth
keycode 246 = XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN
keycode 247 =
```

And a list of all modifiers value with this :

```
$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

There are some raw information in [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database or more polished in [ncurses](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/ncurses.3.asp) API in order to help system developers to overcome this mess.

If you can re-use an existing source code like [nano's one](http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/trunk/nano/src/winio.c?root=nano&view=markup), it should save you a lots of time. Take a look at the "get_escape_seq_kbinput" function to see what I mean.

If you just need modern linux support, it's possible that a call to [keyname](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/keyname/) is enough.

Comment: nano uses either s-lang or (n)curses at the back.ncurses is a spaghetti-monster-code to fight thru. then there's also the loadkeys and family - another bizarre way of doing things. (PS: the nano maintainers really put a lot of work into it)